# How would you get a list of height unbalanced leaf nodes in a binary search tree?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

To know whether a tree is height balanced or not we simply compare the height of left and right sub trees.

However, how do I create a program that will tell me how many nodes are unbalanced and print out those nodes?

Answer (score 0):

As with all things trees: use recursion.

```c
int num_unbalanced(node* root, int* height_out, int should_print) {
    if (!root) { *height_out = 0; return 0; }
    int left_height, right_height;
    int left_unbalanced = num_unbalanced(root->left, &left_height, should_print);
    int right_unbalanced = num_unbalanced(root->right, &right_height, should_print);
    int this_unbalanced = abs(left_height - right_height) > 1;
    *height_out = 1 + max(left_height, right_height);
    if (should_print && this_unbalanced) print_node(root);
    return left_unbalanced + right_unbalanced + this_unbalanced;
}
```